# IE8 Freezes winforms application

Tags: winforms, internet-explorer

We have a large winforms program. On one computer if you are running the program and open IE8 the winforms program freezes and doesn't come back. But if you already have IE8 running when you start the winforms program everything appears to be fine.

The same thing happens regardless of how you start IE8 (normal, no addins, or 64 bit).

My dev box has the same os, motherboard, processor, and memory and it runs fine.

This is on Vista Enterprise x64 Q9550 with 8GB ram.

It runs fine with Firefox 3. The weird thing is there are no web browser controls in the app or anything that should make it related to IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't really browser related. Some of the controls were created on a worker thread so they had no access to the Windows message pump.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail about a message pump? I'm having a similar problem with a .NET WinForms app locking up when you launch IE.

Answer (score 0):

I would first start by trying to open a different browner (i.e. Chrome) to see what happens there.  My guess is that will work but at least its another point of reference for solving the problem.